# How to AttachDBFileName from a .json file in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am running a project using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework. The project works fine building db at my local repository(C:/User/username/db.mdf) when I use the below connection string.

```
{    
"database": {
    "connection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=OdeToFood"      
}
}
```

But, I want my .mdf file to be created in the project root repository so that I can send the entire project for verification to my teacher. I have tried different formats mentioned like

```
"connection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=OdeToFood;AttachDbFilename=~/App_Data/Database1.mdf;
"connection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=OdeToFood;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database2.mdf;
```

but nothing seems to work.

Error Messages repsectively:

```
SqlException: Cannot attach the file '~App_Data\Database1.mdf' as database 'OdeToFood'.
Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\user\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Database2.mdf' as database 'OdeToFood'.
```

Also, I didn't have `App_Data` folder in my project root initially. I added the folder manually.

**Note**: I have tried looking for an answer extensively before posting here. Kindly don't mark it as duplicate.

Comment: try this `<add name="OdeToFoodConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OdeToFood.mdf;Initial Catalog=OdeToFood;Integrated Security=True"         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: the above connection string will create `OdeToFood.mdf` in App_Data folder itself