# How to pass join sql query table result to another method?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working in ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework. I have two tables, `AppointmentDb` and `StudentDb` in my db. I wish to join them in the controller and pass the result to another action method within the controller. What is the return type of this new table that I pass in `Details` action?

```
public ActionResult Index(AdminViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {              
        var innerJoinQuery = from appointment in AppointmentDb
                             join student in StudentDb on appointment.StudentFirstName equals student.FirstName
                             select appointment;
        return View("Details",innerJoinQuery);
    }
}

public ActionResult Details(?????? innerJoinQuery)
{           
    return View();
}
```

**Edit 1:**

From the answers below, I edited to:

```
    public ActionResult Details(IQueryable<Appointment> appointment)
    {

        return View(appointment);
    }
```

I am still unable to call the columns as desired below. Some of them like `AppointmentID` are from `AppointmentDb` and the rest are from `StudentDb`
Below is the View `Details.cshtml`:

```
@model IQueryable<OdeToFood.Entities.Appointment>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Search", "Index")
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppointmentID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentFirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppointmentDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppointmentTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How should I make this `View` work?

**Edit 2:**

I have made the edits as suggested in Edit 1. There is yet another small error in my complete `View.cshtml`. This is the error I receive `foreach cannot operate on Variables of type OdeToFood.ViewModels.AdminDetailsViewModel because it does not contain definition for GetEnumerator`

```
@model AdminDetailsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Search", "Index")
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppointmentID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentFirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentLastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppointmentDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppointmentTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppointmentID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentFirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentLastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppointmentDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppointmentTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Try Object or Dynamic

Comment: One way to find this out yourself is just specify the parameter type as an int or string, and then see what the compiler message says it should be.

Comment: That is one reason to hate `var` when abused  that makes most developers not even think about the type of the object they're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query code returns `IQueryable<AppointmentDb>`:

```
 public ActionResult Details(IQueryable<AppointmentDb> innerJoinQuery)
 {           
        return View();
 }
```

### Approach 2:

Better execute your query first:

```
var innerJoinQuery = (from appointment in AppointmentDb
                     join student in StudentDb 
                     on appointment.StudentFirstName equals student.FirstName
                     select appointment).ToList();
```

Then pass the resulting list:

```
public ActionResult Details(List<AppointmentDb> innerJoinQuery)
{           
    return View();
}
```

### Edit:

You need to create a class to hold data from multiple tables:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public int AppointmentID { set; get; }
    public string StudentFirstName { set; get; }
    // continue the rest
}
```

Then change your query to:

```
from appointment in AppointmentDb
join student in StudentDb
on appointment.StudentFirstName equals student.FirstName
select new MyViewModel()
{
    AppointmentID = AppointmentDb.AppointmentID,
    StudentFirstName = StudentDb.StudentFirstName
    // continue the rest
};
```

Comment: @stuartd Why you are with `IQueryable`?

Comment: @re3el it has to be `IQueryable<AdminDetailsViewModel>` or a list to use foreach. Not one single object.

Comment: it isn't working with `IQueryable<AdminDetailsViewModel>` but `IEnumerable<AdminDetailsViewModel>` removes the error

Comment: @re3el it all depends on what you're passing. Go with `IEnumerable` then.  Or better execute your query using `.ToList()` as specified in the answer and then you `List<AdminDetailsViewModel>` in your View.

Comment: @user3185569 could you look into this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786074/how-to-attachdbfilename-from-a-json-file-in-asp-net-mvc]

Answer (score 1):

You can use object type

```
public ActionResult Details(object innerJoinQuery)
{           
   return View();
}
```